# Facebook GRAPH API, Post object - source attribute expired?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, uiwebview

I save in my iOS app the source attribute of Post of type uploaded_video.
It seems after a few days that i have saved the url, when i try to view the video again, i get the following response :

An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #50.55a9fc3e.1421276863.14643f14

the URL for the video is the following :

[https://fbcdn-video-k-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-xpf1/v/t42.1790-2/10444196_10152319063863246_2117712221_n.mp4?rl=570&vabr=317&oh=127729c369876023938ab52a68a6351b&oe=54776E95&**gda**=1417095592_126ed6763fe32ef3e310fa4a3870401f](https://fbcdn-video-k-a.akamaihd.net/hvideo-ak-xpf1/v/t42.1790-2/10444196_10152319063863246_2117712221_n.mp4?rl=570&vabr=317&oh=127729c369876023938ab52a68a6351b&oe=54776E95&__gda__=1417095592_126ed6763fe32ef3e310fa4a3870401f)

Does someone knows why would this be happening..? I believe some caching on their Akamai servers ..?
What is the purpose of the source attribute then ? The doc says :
"A URL to any Flash movie or video file attached to the post."
It does not mention anything about its validity after a few days ...

How could i manage to the save a perma link to stream the video otherwise ?
(i've tried embedding the video in a UIWebView with the video_id and the following:
https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=%@
but the UIWebview won't play it ...

Kind regards,
Sami

Comment: That is by design. The url expire. You need to use the API to get the URL when you want to watch it

Comment: I think it because they want you to use  theire embed_html the problem is that it return swf which not running on mobile